# How to Choose fields dynamically for Modelforms Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

I want a form to have certain fields based on condition.  The model is pre-defined as follows:

```
class DumUser(models.Model):
    f1 = models.CharField(max_length=100,null=True)
    f2 = models.CharField(max_length=20,null=True)
    f3 = models.CharField(max_length=3,null=True)
    f4 = models.DateField(null=True)
    f3 = models.CharField(max_length=3, null=True)
    f4 = models.DateField(null=True)
```

lets say, a row of null is added to the DumUser table when a user is created (ignore foreign key constraints for now.)

At this point of time, for some processing, I need f1,f2 and f3 [this is determined dynamically, during the current session ]. The database already has the values of f1 and f2.  So i want the form to display editable and compulsory fields f1,f2,and f3 with f1 & f2 displaying the value already in the database.

If the values of f1 & f2 are changed, they must be reflected in the database along with the newly obtained f3.  Please help!

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a 'fields' keyword argument to the [modelform_factory](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/forms/modelforms/#modelform-factory-function) function, which sets what fields the resulting form will contain.
If you cannot use the factory, you can change the `fields` attribute of a form instance after `__init__` (the attribute does not exist before calling `super().__init__()`).